# How can I use an animation at the end of another animation

Tags: android, animation

I am using following code for rotating an image

```
RotateAnimation anim1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, 8, 70);
anim1.setRepeatCount(0);
anim1.setDuration(18000);
anim1.setFillAfter(true);
img7.startAnimation(anim1);
```

After that I am using another animation

```
RotateAnimation anim1 = new RotateAnimation(360, 0, 8, 70);
anim1.setRepeatCount(0);
anim1.setDuration(18000);
anim1.setFillAfter(true);
img7.startAnimation(anim1);
```

When I am using both the animations without any action listener one of them will work....What I actually want, is at the end of the first animation, for the second animation to start...Can anybody help me to do this?

I am not using any XML code for animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why won't you use [Animation.AnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) for the first animation ([setAnimationListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29)) and launch the second when the first one finishes?

Comment: thanx alex.....its working. at the end of first animation, the second animation is working.Now i want to start another animation at the end of second.is it possible?. can i use loop concept here...

Comment: Yes. Why not. Just don't forget to call animation.reset before calling any animation again.

Answer (score 0):

I think [AnimatorSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html) was designed for this.  [Demo](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/animation/BouncingBalls.html) in the sdk.